# Problems booting Kali Linux 1.0.9a 64 bit on Macbook Pro

Tags: osx, dual-boot, kali-linux, macintosh, refind

I have a mid 2009 Macbook Pro that I am trying to dual boot OS X and Kali Linux on.  I replaced my optic drive with my old HDD and replaced my HDD with an SSD.  OS X and my apps are running off of the SSD. My HDD is almost out of space, but my SSD has about 60GB free. I have installed rEFInd and I am using it to boot into Kali Linux by DVD.  I am able to have it start to boot through the first Live option, but when it reaches the following line, it stops executing:

nouvea [DRM] mm: using CRYPT for buffer copies

I have partitioned my hard drive, formatted for MS-DOS, and I have tried re-downloading the .iso and burning it to another DVD. Neither method has worked.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to boot the kernel with the following flag:
nomodeset

Reference -> http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7643468.html?sid=6970e8a0808e5ef07b80015859bfd664

Comment: @iricharson I will post as an answer, im glad it did work out for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7643468.html?sid=6970e8a0808e5ef07b80015859bfd664) booting the kernel with the nomodeset flag solves this problem.